# "NameError: name 'session_conf' is not defined" when try to get reproducible results in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, reproducible-research

I try to get reproducible results in Google Colab by using the following code. 
But I get the error "NameError: name 'session_conf' is not defined".

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'
np.random.seed(1)
rn.seed(1)

from keras import backend as K

if 'tensorflow' == K.backend():
  import tensorflow as tf
  from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
  config = tf.ConfigProto()
  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = true
  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
  config.gpu_options.visible_device_liste = "0"
  set_session(tf.Session(config=config))

tf.set_random_seed(1) 
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)   
K.set_session(sess)   


!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials 

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Has anyone an idea of the reasons why?

Comment: The most obvious reason is that the variable was never defined. This is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the variable `session_conf` in line `sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)`.

Comment: Thanks, of course. Hope that the rest of the code is right.